# Example of a 2D dataset and a classifier stuck at local minimum

Tags: neural-network, classification

We always hear about neural networks getting stuck at local minima, but I cannot visualize one. Can you please give me some examples?

I am not looking for something like below picture and a neural network with only one neuron. Obviously, in this case the (linear) decision boundary will end up being in one of the two locations. I would classify this problem as underfitting rather than getting stuck at local minimum.

[image: sample data on unit square with two classes]

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the typical use of those terms, it is possible for a classifier to *both* be under-fitting and stuck at a local minimum (see below), so is it fair to rephrase your question "what's a simple NN that is stuck at a local minimum, but is not under-fit".

Depends how contrived you're willing to let the example be, since a realistic NN would be initialized with random parameters which would be tough to analyze, and optimized with SGD (the stochasticity also makes it tough to analyze).

If you're willing to accept that:

### a somewhat contrived example

I hope the code will be generally self explanatory, but the idea is to set all parameters to zero and to use
and generate data that is symmetric so that the gradient is also zero. You'll see that `param.grad` is indeed zero
when `init_zeros=True` and so the weights never change - its a local optimum.

But it's not a global optimum, since initializing elsewhere gives a non-zero gradient, and a much lower loss is achievable.

```
import torch

dtype = torch.float
device = torch.device("cpu")

learning_rate = 0.0001

# Make some data
xys = torch.linspace(-2, 2,steps=5)
x, y = torch.meshgrid( xys, xys )
X = torch.stack((x,y), dim=2).reshape(25,2)
gt = torch.tensor([
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ], 
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ], 
        [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 ], 
        [ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 ], 
        [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]],
        dtype=torch.float).reshape(25,1)

def train_model(num_hidden=25, num_iters=5000, init_zeros=False):

    loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='sum')
    model = torch.nn.Sequential(
        torch.nn.Linear(2, num_hidden),
        torch.nn.ReLU(),
        torch.nn.Linear(num_hidden, 1),
        torch.nn.ReLU())

    if( init_zeros ):
        with torch.no_grad():
            model[0].weight.fill_(0.)
            model[0].bias.fill_(0.)
            model[2].weight.fill_(0.)
            model[2].bias.fill_(0.)

    #train 
    for t in range( num_iters ):
        pred = model(X)
        loss=loss_fn(pred,gt)
        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for param in model.parameters():
                param -= learning_rate * param.grad
    
    final_loss = loss_fn(model(X), gt)
    return final_loss, model


final_loss_stuck, ms = train_model(init_zeros=True)
final_loss, m = train_model()
print( f"final loss (stuck):      {final_loss_stuck}" )
print( f"final loss (less_stuck): {final_loss}" )
```

Running the above, I get the output:

```
final loss (stuck):      17.0
final loss (less_stuck): 2.038207769393921
```

### a little discussion

Under / over fitting has to do with how changing the *model* changes your predictions. Local minima relates to model optimization: once I've chosen and fixed my model, how do changing the *parameters* change performance. So I usually think of them as independent issues. Because of that, I agree that for a linear classifier, your example is under-fit, but it *also* could get stuck at a local minimum.

Back to your example - yes a linear classifier under-fits: so changing the model to something more flexible will help. But, say we've chosen a linear model, and initialize it at the upper-left boundary.  No local change will improve classification performance, so it is in a local minimum. But not the global minimum (for a linear classifier).